# Should you chew your food 50 times?

Tags: nutrition

I have heard my entire life you should focus on chewing your food at least 50 times. The saliva in your mouth supposedly sends signals to the brain that prepare acids in your stomach in advance, and this important for indigestion.

How much of this is truth ?

Comment: Rishi, I have edited your question to leave only the core about chewing your food often enough. *Succes in life* is hard to correlate with indigestion.

Comment: @JanDoggen thanks for making it better, how ever i will share a link relating it to our career and success as well :)

Comment: Note that the internet is [full of pages](https://www.google.nl/search?q=chew+your+food) claiming a wide range of numbers ([30](http://www.healthextremist.com/how-many-times-should-you-chew-your-food/), [32](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2015/12/12/chewing-food-thoroughly.aspx) ,[40](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2020403/Chew-mouthful-food-40-TIMES-help-lose-weight.html)).

Comment: Yes but if you type "Drink your food and chew your water by R Madhavan" on YouTube, you will find he is claiming he learn that the quality of your life in every aspect depends on how and when you eat.

He went to some wellness center (150 year old) in austria paid a lot of money

Comment: I was told 20 as a kid. 50 is new to me.